# Deserializing JSON to C# using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the below JSON

```
[{"name":"sEcho","value":3},{"name":"iColumns","value":7}]
```

When i deserialize using JOSN.NET  i ll get o/p as List of name and values

```
name sEcho
value 3
```

Is it possible somehow to get like

```
sEcho 3
IColumn 7
```

This is the string am getting from `JQUERY DataTable` to my controller and am trying to convert into a class using Newton soft .

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to dictionary

```
string json = @"[{""name"":""sEcho"",""value"":3},{""name"":""iColumns"",""value"":7}]";

var dict = JArray.Parse(json)
           .ToDictionary(x => (string)x["name"], x => (string)x["value"]);

Console.WriteLine(dict["sEcho"]);
```